# Open Intent url from browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an asp classic site used by mobile devices (`Android` and `iOS`) that calls a native application using Intent by calling it from javascript. Sometimes it works, and other time it can't open the application. In iOS it works all time. The call is like

```
appNativeName://sign?fileid=yyyyyyy&rtservlet=serverUrl&key=xxxxx
```

Have Android such control or verification of intents URL's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is not the way I'm calling the intent, the problem was the browser. It works perfectly under desktop version with all browser except for the old mozilla versions.
When accessing through mobile, the problem was happening only on android devices as I mentioned above, and the solution has been using "Opera" browser, because it has not limitation on sending data. My app sends Base64 data, so Chrome and Samsung browser gave me error when sending more than 3 Mb aprox. I also tried to use mozilla for android, but it has a really big problem, that can't let install user certificate (what a shame!) so finally with Opera all the process is working fine :)

Hope this will help other people fighting in it like me ;)

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManufest.xml set for activity you want to be opened from browser intent-filter:

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="yourscheme"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Then in Activity's onCreate() method catch that intent and do whatever you want to do:

```
val intent = intent
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == intent.action) {
        val uri = intent.data
        if (uri?.host?.matches("something_you_need") == true) {
            doSomething(token)
        } else {
            doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
```

Then from your web you can call something like: `yourscheme://something_you_need`

Answer (score 0):

```
An intent URI has the following layout (all optional - heh!)

intent:
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
   #Intent; 
      package=[string]; 
      action=[string]; 
      category=[string]; 
      component=[string]; 
      scheme=[string]; 
      type=[string]
      S.*=[string];
   end; 

Link : https://paul.kinlan.me/every-browser-should-support-intent-urls/
```

Use this link.